# How do I focus on the item in my navbar when I changes to a different page?

Tags: jquery

I'm using to use jQuery to add some effects on the nav link when I'm on the different pages.
But every time I jump to the next page, it will refresh the website.
How can I manage to have effect wherever the page I am on?

Here's a example.

```
<nav class="control-panel">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="./index.html" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="./assignment.html" class="nav-link">Assignment</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
.nav-link{
  color: green;
}
.nav-link--active{
  color: red;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".nav-link").click(function (e) {
    $(this)
      .addClass("nav-link--active")
      .parent()
      .siblings()
      .find(".nav-link")
      .removeClass("nav-link--active");
  });
});
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently just adding a class to your `nav-link` items on the `click` event. That will only work if you stay on the same page. As soon as you load another page, that state gets lost. You need to add the same functionality (of adding the `active` class) on pageload.

First you would need to get the current path with

```
let path = window.location.pathname;
```

Assuming your URL is `https://www.example.com/index.html`, `window.location.pathname` will return `/index.html`

Then you need to compare it with the `href` attribute in your `nav-link`

```
$('.nav-link').each(function() {
   if(path === $(this).attr('href')) {
     $(this).addClass('active');
   }
});
```

In total:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let path = window.location.pathname;
  $('.nav-link').each(function() {
     if(path === $(this).attr('href')) {
       $(this).addClass('active');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works now!
But I don't quite understand what's the difference between ./index.html & /index.html.
The part I know is that ./index.html means the file is under the root.
It wouldn't work after I delete the ".".
Why's that?
Again, thanks for your help!!

Comment: I dont think that `window.location.pathname` returns `./path` ?! Anyways `/` = root directory, `./` = current working directory `../` = parent directory

Answer (score 0):

One options would be to store the link text in `localStorage` and use that to add your styling to the appropriate link after the DOM loads after the navigation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-link").click(function (e) {
      //Save the link text in localStorage for use in styling after a page refresh/navigation
      localStorage.setItem('linktext', $(this).text());       
    });
    //If localStorage has the key, set the appropriate link style
    if(localStorage.getItem("linktext") !== null){
        $('.nav-link').each(function(){
             if($(this).text() === localStorage.getItem("linktext")){
                 //Set your styling on this anchor element
             }
        });
    }
});
```

You can also use `sessionStorage` or a `cookie`.

Comment: The problem with that approach is, that the local storage only changes if  a link is clicked, if the user uses the browser history, another link to a page or, types in the page, the wrong element will be highlighted