# Horizontal scroll menu centered on active item in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling

I've made horizontal scroll menu for mobile in my wordpress website. Now I want it to be centered on active menu item on page load. I found this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
}); function onScroll(event){
$('#menu-center a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    currLink.removeClass("active");
});
}
```

I cannot make it work. I've changed all '$' to 'jQuery' but this did not help. My main goal is menu to be centered on active item on page change/load.

Here's wordpress menu

```
<nav class="someclassname">
<ul id="menuscroll">
    <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Mneu item</a></li>
    <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Mneu item</a></li>
    <li class="menuli active"><a href="#">Mneu item</a></li>
    <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Mneu item</a></li>
    <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Mneu item</a></li>
    <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Mneu item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I focus on the item in my navbar when I changes to a different page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64915536/how-do-i-focus-on-the-item-in-my-navbar-when-i-changes-to-a-different-page)

Comment: are you using a custom menu or `wp_nav_menus`?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't work